# delete entire row if cell G ="YES"

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

hi I have a code to delete entire row if cell in column G ="YES". It works fine, but when copy cells from one workbook to another it deletes the last row that is paste. Same as if I drag cell to auto fill.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
Application.EnableEvents = False
'If Cell that is edited is in column U and the value is completed then
If Target.Column = 7 And Target.Value = "YES" Then
    'Define last row on completed worksheet to know where to place the row of data
    LrowCompleted = Sheets("EQUIP. OFF RENT").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'Copy and paste data
    Range(Target.Row & ":" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("EQUIP. OFF RENT").Range("A" & LrowCompleted + 1)
   End If
   If Target.Column = 7 And Target.Value = "YES" Then

    Range(Target.Row & ":" & Target.Row).Delete
    End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: A paste/fill is a single change so your function only gets triggered once, and your function at most deletes 1 row. Have you tried using a loop?

Comment: Nick, I have not tried loop for I am not familiar with it. I am just learning the vba.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing your code, it's a classical problem with the `On Error Resume Next`, combined with the `Application.EnableEvents = False`. 
Even if there is an error in the code, the job is still running. That's why the last cell is deleted after a paste for example.

To avoid this, i simply erase the error resume next and the enableevents, and add this line before the first If statement :

```
If Target.Column = 1 Then Exit Sub
```

So please try this :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 1 Then Exit Sub

If Target.Column = 7 And Target.Value = "YES" Then
    'Define last row on completed worksheet to know where to place the row of data
    LrowCompleted = Sheets("EQUIP. OFF RENT").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'Copy and paste data
    Range(Target.Row & ":" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("EQUIP. OFF RENT").Range("A" & LrowCompleted + 1)
End If
If Target.Column = 7 And Target.Value = "YES" Then
    Range(Target.Row & ":" & Target.Row).Delete
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Mike, the code you posted stopped deleting the last row when copied, but now when I type YES in column G nothing happens.